# Is there a full list of emotes available for Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

I know when you enter "/?" it gives you a few, but generally that is just a sampling. For example in WoW there were literally hundreds of different ones, some with corresponding animations or voices. I'd like to know if there is a full list available anywhere, or if anyone knows of some beyond those listed in help.

Comment: What makes you think the ones you see in /? are "just a sampling"?  Have you seen any that aren't listed there?

Comment: @Shinrai - It is speculation based on other games where emotes exist. I'll go through a few that would commonly be available tonight like /dance and see if I can find a secret one.

Comment: I just wanted to confirm this is speculation.  I wasn't sure if you were trying to say that you'd seen some that weren't documented - the question as written is misleading.  (Personally I can't imagine there'd be any more than are documented...this isn't exactly an MMO.  I'm surprised there is anything more complicated than '/me' honestly.)

Comment: Blizzard has also shown a propensity through patched to add things like this, so it may be coming but not currently available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the menu, the full list of emotes are:

- Follow
- Give
- Thanks
- Sorry
- Bye
- Die
- Run
- Wait
- Go
- Help
- Yes
- No
- Stay There
- Attack
- Retreat
- Hold
- Take Objective

By default, only the first 10 (the ones bolded) are bound, and they are bound to numpad 1 through numpad 0, in the order listed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can dance by pressing /dance. It is not a command in the Help when you /?, but it is actually one that works.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into options then to I belive controls. You can see a list of the possible emotes near the bottom. Sadly I am not home at the moment so I can't recall the exact options path.